# Can not connect to Amazon EMR cluster with PuTTY

Tags: putty, amazon-emr

I created EMR cluster with standard configuration.

Then I allowed inbound SSH traffic on port 22 for the corresponding security group. I added the following rules:

[image]

Then I followed the instructions:

[image]

But I am getting the error:

> Server refused our key

[image]

I didn't manage to find an answer here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-server-refused-our-key/.

I tried to connect from another workstation (with Windows 7). Here I am getting another error:

[image]

I created EC2 instance and successfully connected to it with EC2 connect. But when I tried to connect with SSH - PuTTY raising the error:

[image]

I also tried to connect from cygwin (got an error "Server refused our key") and from PuTTY 32-bit (the same error).

Answer (score 0):

I just generated another key pair and it worked.